# Double quaternion skinning artifacts

Tags: computational-geometry, animation, gltf, motion, quaternions

This is technically about PGA motors, but dual quaternions are a subalgebra of PGA so for all given purposes it's the same idea.

I have an animation in gltf, specified as inverse bind pose matrices, quaternions and translations. I am turning that data into dual quaternions (motors), which gives me a mostly correct animation with some artifacts.

The artifacts are caused by a sign issue on the rotations. Basically, a 3D rotation has 2 representations, the $\alpha$ rotation around axis $A$, and the $-2\pi + \alpha$ rotation around axis $-A$. i.e. you can get to the same place whether you rotate CCW by $\alpha$ or CW by $2\pi - \alpha$.

The point where this causes an issue is when blending. depending of which of the 2 rotation representations you have when blending, the operation $w_1 R1 + w_2 R_2$ can yield a very similar or a very different result, for example if $R_1 = R2$ and $w_1 = w_2 = 0.5$ then we just have the same rotation, but if $R_1 = - R_2$ then we get the 0 quaternion, which is not even a rotation.

This manifests as candywrapping, like in this image:

[image]

If you know that a joint is candywrapped after blending, you can fix the issue by negating one of the motors you are blending together, for example in this particular model I know joint 8 is the elbow and I can fix the candy wrapping by negating the joint:

```rust
 let index = 8;
        skin.inverse_poses[index] = -1.0 * skin.inverse_poses[index];
```

[image]

I can fix the entire animation by manually inspecting the model for regions where this happens and negating one of the motors/quaternions. However this is stupidly time consuming, this is something that should be automated, there has to be a mathematical formulation that tells me when to flip the sign.

At first I thought that it was just a matter of always selecting the positive scalar version of the quaternion, i.e. doing this:

```rust
            let joint = res.joints[index];
            let m1 = anim.joint_animations[joint[0] as usize].rotations[0] * res.skin.inverse_poses[joint[0] as usize];
            let m2 = anim.joint_animations[joint[1] as usize].rotations[0] * res.skin.inverse_poses[joint[1] as usize];
            let m3 = anim.joint_animations[joint[2] as usize].rotations[0] * res.skin.inverse_poses[joint[2] as usize];
            let m4 = anim.joint_animations[joint[3] as usize].rotations[0] * res.skin.inverse_poses[joint[3] as usize];

            let weights = res.skin_weights[index];
            let combined = weights[0] * m1 + weights[1] * m2 + weights[2] * m3 + weights[3] * m4;
            if combined.s() < 0.0
            {
                for j_anim in &mut anim.joint_animations[joint[1] as usize].rotations
                {
                    *j_anim = -1.0 * *j_anim;
                }
            }
```

Or in english, for every set of 4 joints that should be blended together, see if the resulting motor has a negative scalar and if it does, negate the motor.

This is not the correct criterion, it does fix some of the issues but not all, and it causes some issues itself.

What is the correct way to identify if a set of rotations affecting a joint should be flipped? Alternatively, how do I properly extract the quaternions from the original data?